# How to make rules so two QGIS contour maps don't cross

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, contour

I'm creating multiple contour maps stacked on one another over one geographical area based on the depths of various attributes. In some cases, given the mass of data and occasional inaccurate data, the contour maps will 'cross' each other. For example, contour A should always have lower depth than contour B, but because of inaccurate data point A1, contour A has a greater depth than B at point A1.

It becomes too much work to just exclude certain data points by hand, as there are so many. Any ideas on how to set a rule where if contour A crosses contour B, the depth for A is automatically set to a certain distance above B? Or perhaps a way in QGIS/SQL to systematically exclude data? Note that only one depth reading accompanies a data point, which accompany a predetermined categorization for contour A or contour B.

Comment: Hi @M.Hagerty, I could not follow your question, I think you can improve it. In general, procedures for producing contour lines make them in a way that they do not cross each other, so it is quite impossible to set up a new rule to avoid somethng is not happening. But from your quiestion I am understanding you need a way to exclude same points, that is called *classification*, which will strongly depend of the nature of your data